# How to send smileys/emotions (images) with messages in xmpp in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xmpp

How to send smileys/emotions (images) with messages in xmpp in iphone sdk ?

Answer (score 0):

Emoticons in XMPP are sent as plain text (e.g. `:)` and `:(`), and are not terribly well-standardized.  We've [tried](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0038.html) a couple of times, but it turns out to be surprisingly difficult to achieve consensus on this topic.  Your best bet is to pick an open source client and emulate what they do.  Here are the lists from Exodus: ([MSN-style](http://code.google.com/p/exodus/source/browse/trunk/exodus/msn-emoticons/icondef.xml), [Yahoo!-style](http://code.google.com/p/exodus/source/browse/trunk/exodus/yahoo-emoticons/icondef.xml)), which I point to just because I knew where they were.

Answer (score 0):

I havent implemented this but

You can enable EMOJI keyboard to send the emoticons by enabling this keyboard from settings
you can also refer to

http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/02/freemoji-access-emoji-for-free.ars

Vikas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the smileys as images (binary data) within the message, [XEP-231](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0231.html) is the way to go.